# General dimensional solution to fast sweeping quadratic equation

Tags: finite-element, algorithms, nonlinear-equations, differential-equations

I am reading Hongkai Zhao's paper [The Fast Sweeping method](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-03-fall/Papers/zhao_fastsweep1.pdf). I have implemented the method in 2D and now I want to move onto 3D.

However section 2.6 confuses me.

The article says:

[image]
[image]

But I have no idea how that is actually supposed to work. i.e. On a purely computational level, what steps do I actually follow to solve that quadratic equation?

Comment: The function at the start is monotonous, if indeed $(x-a)^+=\max(0,x-a)$. You can find the correct $p$ by just comparing the function values at the segment nodes. It is the largest index where $(a_p-a_1)^2+...+(a_p-a_{p-1})^2<f_{i,j}^2h^2$. You can use bisection search until the correct $p$ is identified.